# Was Adam Jewish?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, adam

As I understand it, both Adam and Avraham had direct communication with God. Did Adam's communication with God make him Jewish? If not, what is the difference between the belief system of the descendants of Adam and those of Avraham?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Being Jewish isn't just about beliefs; somebody could believe exactly the same things about God and Torah as Jews do and not be Jewish.  Do you mean to ask specifically about the differences in their beliefs, or how beliefs relate to Jewishness, or whether direct communication with God is limited to Jews?

Comment: very related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8646/759

Comment: @MonicaCellio I am asking about the difference in their beliefs and if there were any Jews before Avraham.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, I read that question also during my research here, it implies that Avraham is the first Jew, but at the same time [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46248/did-anyone-recognize-pray-follow-worship-god-between-adam-and-avraham/46253#46253) by Scimonster implies that Chanoch (Enoch) and Noach also meet some of the key points (depending on several variables that are unclear) If being Jewish is simply being one of the chosen, who was born on or after the time of Avraham, than Adam could not have been Jewish, though as Monica says they may have the same beliefs.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A was that there was not supposed to be a need for a Jewish people at all.

Adam was supposed to pass the test of jealousy, lust, and honor and that would have been it.

He failed at all three. then humanity as a whole was given three chances to rectify these three.

they failed at all three.

Plan B, now it's no longer all of humanity that rectifies the sin of adam but a small group within humanity - the descendants of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacod, each of which represents the rectification of one of the three flaws.

source [lecture](http://dafyomireview.com/audio/m04-3_flaws_of_man_and_role_of_jews.mp3) by Rabbi Uziel Milevsky